# Color and background color not changing while hovered

Tags: css, hover

I have a div block with an image, a heading and a paragraph. I want to change the background-color and the text color of that div when i hover on it but only the background-color changes, the color tag is simply ignored. How can I fix this?

```
.Div_Systemingenieur {
  width: 18%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: white;
  color: #24252a;
 }

.Systemingenieur_Text {
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px;
 border-color: white;
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 10%;
 color: #24252a;
}

.Heading_Systemingenieur {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
 .Div_Systemingenieur:hover {
   background-color: #24252a;
   color: white;
}
```

**NOTE**: I am still very new to programming with css, and I am doing this for a school project.
PS: some of the names are written in german, as it is my native language.
Have a great rest of your day!
Lucien

Comment: It does not get “ignored”, but `.Systemingenieur_Text` still has its own color set, and you did not change _that one_. If you don’t need to explicitly specify the color for that one for some reason - then simply remove color from that element, so that it can directly inherit it from the parent. _If_ you need to explicitly specify it for this element, then use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), to format this element when its parent gets hovered - `.Div_Systemingenieur:hover .Systemingenieur_Text { … }`

Comment: That did it! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
.Div_Systemingenieur {
  width: 18%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: white;
  color: #24252a;
 }

.Systemingenieur_Text {
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px;
 border-color: white;
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.Heading_Systemingenieur {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
 .Div_Systemingenieur:hover {
   background-color: #24252a;
   color: white;
}
```